# Pulling version out of string with bash script

Tags: bash

I would like to check the local version of Hugo.

```
$ hugo version
Hugo Static Site Generator v0.49 linux/amd64 BuildDate: 2018-09-24T10:03:17Z
```

What would be a safe and future-proof method to extract `v0.49` from the output above with a bash script?

Comment: Since you don't control `hugo` you can't guarantee that anything would be future-proof.

Comment: Just for the record, the output of `hugo version` on my system is `Hugo Static Site Generator v0.59.0-DEV/extended linux/amd64 BuildDate: unknown`, so you might want to be careful with any solutions posted here.

Comment: What do you want to do with the output?

Comment: @TomFenech I want to exit 1 and stop the script if the version isn't equal to what I expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're better off using `grep` like this:

```
$ hugo version
Hugo Static Site Generator v0.59.0-DEV/extended linux/amd64 BuildDate: unknown
$ version=v0.59
$ hugo version | grep -q "${version//./\\.}" && echo "correct version"
correct version
$ version=v0.43
$ hugo version | grep -q "${version//./\\.}" || echo "incorrect version"
incorrect version
```

`grep -q` exits successfully if the regex matches, so can be used with shell conditional constructs. I am using a parameter expansion to replace `.` with `\.`, so that the version number can be used in a regular expression (otherwise the `.` would match any character).

The [bash docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) explain how parameter expansion works (see **`${parameter/pattern/string}`**). Basically, `${version//./\\.}` globally (`/`) replaces  a `.` with a `\.`. Two `\` are required in the replacement string, because the first one escapes the second one.

Comment: Thanks - would you mind breaking down the slashes and dots after version here `"${version//./\\.}"` for someone who is unfamiliar with bash.

Comment: @jchi2241 I updated my answer with an explanation and a link to the docs.

Answer (score 1):

A `sed` expression can be fairly general and still work so long as you version remains in the form of

```
v[any number of digits].[any number of digits]
```

To use `sed`, you can simply pipe the output of `hugo version` to your `sed` expression, e.g.

```
$ hugo version | sed 's/^.*\(v[0-9][0-9]*[.][0-9][0-9]*\).*$/\1/'
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your output that would result in:

```
$ hugo version | sed 's/^.*\(v[0-9][0-9]*[.][0-9][0-9]*\).*$/\1/'
v0.49
```

You can capture the result in a variable using *command substitution*, e.g.

```
hversion=$(hugo version | sed 's/^.*\(v[0-9][0-9]*[.][0-9][0-9]*\).*$/\1/')
```

**Explanation of `sed` Expression**

The breakdown of the `sed` expression is the normal substitution `s/find/replace/` where:

- `find` is:

  - `^.*` - and number of characters from the beginning,
  - `\(`  - begin a capture group to save what follows,
  - `v` - the character `'v'`,
  - `[0-9][0-9]*` - at least 1 digit followed by zero or more digits,
  - `[.]` - a decimal point (or period), followed by
  - `[0-9][0-9]*` - at least 1 digit followed by zero or more digits,
  - `\)` - end the capture group saving the captured content,
  - `.*$` - all characters to the end of the string.
- `replace` is:

  - `\1` a single backreference to the text from the first capture group.

That is the extent of it. A normal substitution using a single backreference which will work the same for `v0.49` as it will for `v243.871`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use Bash's builtin `read` like this:

```sh
read -r _ _ _ _  hugo_version _ < <(hugo version)
```